# How do I animate scrolling, using $location.hash() in ionic and an Angular Service?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, animation, ionic-framework, anchor-scroll

I have a list of filtered items on one page that links to the full list of items in another page and I want to navigate to that page and scroll to the item i selected in the filtered list.

I tried using 2 different methods - `$anchorScroll` - which works but has no animation properties. So, the next view would just appear with the item "pre scrolled" and then be "elastic to that position." Then I tried to implement a service like so:

```
.factory('ScrollService',function(){
var service = {};

service.scrollTo = function(eID) {

    // This scrolling function 
    // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript

    var startY = currentYPosition();
    var stopY = elmYPosition(eID);
    var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
    if (distance < 100) {
        scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
    }
    var speed = Math.round(distance / 10);
    if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
    var step = Math.round(distance / 25);
    var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
    var timer = 0;
    if (stopY > startY) {
        for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
        } return;
    }
    for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
        setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
        leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
    }

    function currentYPosition() {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
        // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
        if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
        return 0;
    }

    function elmYPosition(eID) {
        var elm = document.getElementById(eID);
        var y = elm.offsetTop;
        var node = elm;
        while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
            node = node.offsetParent;
            y += node.offsetTop;
        } return y;
    }

};

return service;
});
```

This did not work as i needed to call it twice for some reason and there was no animation either.

Controller call:

```
var gotoItem = function (eID){
  // set the location.hash to the id of
  // the element you wish to scroll to.
  $location.hash(eID);

  // call $anchorScroll()
  ScrollService.scrollTo(eID);

};
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function(){
   $timeout(function(){
      gotoItem('-KR9Z3yDVb6TVEdk38z6'); //tried hardcoding the element...fail
    }, 500); ///trying to hold off until visible...fail
  });
```

The URL construction is as follows:
`<baseURL>/<ItemPage>#<ItemID>` where the `<ItemID>` is the id of the item in the full list.

`$location.hash()` gets the correct "id" - how can I animate the scroll similar to this site, actually, and eventually do a similar CSS highlight after scroll? WITH OUT THE NEW SCROLL TO POSITION BEING STICKY.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions???

Comment: is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: It's been 20 days...anyone out there?